# Passing Core Data to another View Using Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

What I am trying to accomplish is to pass core data from one view controller to another. I have a tableView and when a certain cell is tapped I would like the next screen to display the name of the person on the cell as a label on the next ViewController. I have two entities that I have made using core data called 'name' and 'image'. I am only trying to pass the 'name' data for now. Here is what I have in my `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

    if(segue.identifier == "moreInfo"){
        let objectController: QuotesVC = segue.destinationViewController as! QuotesVC
        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

        let object: Friend = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Friend
        objectController.object = object
    }
}
```

And here is what I have for my 'QuotesVC' View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class QuotesVC: UIViewController {

    var object: Friend? = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var personImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var personName: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureView(object!)      
    }

    func configureView(friend: Friend) {
        personName.text = friend.name
    }
```

I am wondering if maybe I am trying to retrieve an object when I haven't actually created an object in the cell? When I tap on a cell to take me to the next ViewController, I receive this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no object at index 2 in
>   section at index 0'

---

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is the problem with the `fetchedResultController`, it doesn't have any object in that particular `indexPath`.

Comment: ... which begs the question what are the datasource methods for the tableview?  If you've implemented those in the customary fashion, you shouldn't have rows with no underlying object in the FRC.